# NGINX Proxy http://somedomain.com/proxythis to React App

Tags: node.js, nginx, proxy, flask

I have a project that requires me to frontend a react app. I don't know much about frontend serverside applications. Nodejs, flask, react and such but I need to work with the developer to proxy it.

What I currently have is a Location redirect. This works for

Location /proxythis
  proxy_pass http://anotherserver.com:3001;

which is where the flask app lives. There are 3 routes there. One for /proxythis, one for /public where css and js are built and the last one is /api.

I can't have /proxythis stick and serve /proxythis/public from the one Location block. The server responds with /public or off the domain, ignoring /proxythis so then of course the app breaks as I can't get through NGINX.

I think the issue is more in how the flask app is run and its routes, that's my guess, and how it presents the paths. If the public and api paths were relative to the application root then it should work, or at least the assets will be served. I just don't know if this is a good practice or if there is another solution that is better.